# Simple MySQL SELECT with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

How do I filter by columns with PDO? I have the following:

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * from blog ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4');
```

This obviously returns the last 4 results. I want to add one more step and filter it by a specific column named `category`

So, something like:

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * from blog WHERE category=NAME-HERE ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using prepared statements with named parameters:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE category=:category ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4");
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
$stmt->execute();
```

PDO will automatically wrap quotes around the `category` parameter if it is a string.

If the value of `$category` isn't coming from an untrusted source, you can modify your code as follows:

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * from blog WHERE category='$category' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4");
/** OR **/
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * from blog WHERE category="'.$category.'" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4');
```

Note that in the above case, you *do* need quotes around the `$category` variable since you're building the query string yourself.

Comment: Is binding required if the `SELECT` is not user generated?

Comment: @Justin: You don't need the quotes around `:category` in the SQL anyway.  In fact, if you include them, the `:category` would be interpreted as a literal string, not a parameter.